# Android AndEngine animated sprite not animating correctly

Tags: android, animation, sprite, andengine

I've got an animated sprite named player that I change the animation and direction of using an onscreencontrol.  The animation seems to get stuck and/or repeat the first frame without ever going through a complete animation cycle.  I suspect the onscreencontrol updatehandler is resetting the animation before it has time to go through all the steps?  I'm not sure whats wrong here, this seems like it should work:

```
final AnalogOnScreenControl velocityOnScreenControl = new AnalogOnScreenControl(x1, y1, this.BoundChaseCamera,this.ScreenControlBaseTextureRegion,this.ScreenControlKnobTextureRegion, 0.1f,new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener() {
    @Override
    public void onControlChange(
    final BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,
    final float pValueX, final float pValueY) {
    /* player position */
    float spotX = player.getX() + 1 * TILE_WIDTH * pValueX;
    float spotY = player.getY() + 1 * TILE_HEIGHT * pValueY;
    /* if player position within bounds of map */
        if (spotX < TMXMapLayer.getWidth()
        && spotY < TMXMapLayer.getHeight()
        && spotX >= 0 && spotY >= 0) {
        /* Set player velocity */
final Vector2 velocity = Vector2Pool.obtain(pValueX * 3, pValueY * 3);
PlayerBody.setLinearVelocity(velocity);
Vector2Pool.recycle(velocity);
/* Math to determine the direction of movement */
double dirDouble = (Math.atan2(pValueX, pValueY)
    / (Math.PI / 2) + 2);
float direction = (int) Math.round(dirDouble)
    % DirectionState;
       /* if movement is N,E,S or W, do animation */
    if (direction == 0) { // If Go North
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 0,2, true); // north

    } else if (direction == 1) { // If Go West
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 9,11, true); // west

    } else if (direction == 2) { // If Go South
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 6,8, true); // south

    } else if (direction == 3) { // If Go East
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 3,5, true); // east
    }   
       }
    }
```

Comment: what is DirectionState variable ?

Answer (score 3):

You're resetting the animation on every update with this code

```
if (direction == 0) { // If Go North
player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 0,2, true); // north

} else if (direction == 1) { // If Go West
player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 9,11, true); // west

} else if (direction == 2) { // If Go South
player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 6,8, true); // south

} else if (direction == 3) { // If Go East
player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 3,5, true); // east
}
```

you're not verifying if the direction has changed, to correct this you should add an external if to check if the direction has changed. Your code should be like

```
if(direction != lastDirection){
    lastDirection = direction;
    if (direction == 0) { // If Go North
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 0,2, true); // north

    } else if (direction == 1) { // If Go West
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 9,11, true); // west

    } else if (direction == 2) { // If Go South
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 6,8, true); // south

    } else if (direction == 3) { // If Go East
    player.animate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200 }, 3,5, true); // east
    }
}
```

the variable lastDirection should be external to you onControlChange scope